# ModRewrite с условиями

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Нужно вот что сделать

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1111\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://3333.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Вот есть правило. По этому правилу с домена 1111.ru все запросы переадресовываются на 3333.ru

Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь вводит 1111.ru без дополнительных параметров перекидывало на 2222.ru, а все остальные как и ранее 3333.ru

Comment: Что под параметрами подразумеваете?

Comment: Если домен https://1111.ru/ то кидает на https://2222.ru/, а если https://1111.ru/lalala, то на https://3333.ru/lalala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1111\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://3333.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1111\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://2222.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

P.S. Если нужно передавать get параметры, то добавьте флаг `QSA` к `R=301,L`.